# bash script stops apache2 service on bootup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, bash

I have been trying for while to run my script, it is called **cservice** and i placed it on `/etc/init.d/` 
then i gave it the permission to be executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/cservice
```

I can run it when i call it `./cservice` and runs perfectly, this script is calling a php script `#!/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/service.php` it works when i run it manually but when i put it on start up with this command

then i put it on boot up

```
sudo update-rc.d cservice defaults
```

and i get this warning

```
insserv: warning: script 'cservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

then when i test it rebooting my server my apache server doesn't boot up and i have to do it manually what is happening this? However when i remove it my apache server boot up normally.

Need help please i am very new on ubuntu.

How can i make my script run without affecting my apache server.

Comment: I just searched for `LSB tags` in Google, and it showed many articles what you are missing. Please make a minimum effort of self research before posting questions over here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no minimum effort for self research

Comment: Please be aware that from Ubuntu 15 onwards it has switched to systemd and you should be creating service units rather than system V style init scripts (even though systemd does provide some backward compatibility for those) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by putting this after my script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          cservice
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: cservice
# Description:       cservice server daemon
### END INIT INFO
```